# how to execute the contents from one php file from a different php file

Tags: php, database

￼I am trying to create a login file where the db is created first if it doesn't exist. The connection of the db is in db.php, trying to run that file when the index.php is called.

I know there are similar question that answers to use include, but for some weird reason the db.php file is not getting executed. If anyone could guide in the right direction would be great.

The image of both files

[image: the image of both files]

Comment: Are both the files in the same directory?

Comment: check if you have <?php open tag in another file

Comment: nice, so everytime the user refreshes the page you will create a new database

Comment: In fact, seeing how that is a "require" and not (just) an "include". It must be successfully including it, since it was halt the script if it wasn't?

Comment: Feel like I'm gift wrapping a turd here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic to create a DB if it doesn't exists seems incorrect. Try with the below code in db.php

```
<?php
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pass = 'root';
$db = "NEWaBBC";

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
try {
     $conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);
} catch (Exception $exc) {
    $sql = "CREATE DATABASE ".$db;
    $conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass);
    if($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) echo "created";
    else echo "error: ".$conn->error;
}
```

Note: do not close the connection at the end of db.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use the include method. 
Take this as your directory tree:
Root>>PHPScripts>>db.php
Root>>main>>index.php

You can do

```
include '../PHPScripts/db.php';
```

That will essentially put the code from that file right into your script so you can use all its variables ect.

Read more here:

[Include PHP](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp)

Comment: If it isn't getting executed, you have directory problems, give us your directory tree and we can help you